# Box2D Joint.GetReactionForce equivalent in Sprite Kit

Tags: box2d, sprite-kit, revolute-joints

When working with pure, unwrapped Box2D and Cocos2D, I used to be able to get the reaction force on a joint with a beautiful function called GetReactionForce. I've recently started trying Sprite Kit physics and I don't seem to find a similar thing. As far as I know there's no ready one. Is there a way I can achieve this in Sprite Kit somehow? The physics engine is still Box2D but not all the capabilities have been made available. I think it could be done using the properties like mass, density, velocity etc. of the bodies forming joint. But I have no idea how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not readily available and I can't think of a way to emulate or work around it using Sprite Kit's built-in physics.

That said it's fairly easy to just ignore Sprite Kit's physics and instead embed Box2D (or Chipmunk) in your app. You can step the world in the scene's didSimulatePhysics message (gets called even with physicsWorld property being nil). You can store references to nodes inside the body's userData, and after stepping enumerate the bodies and update their node's (obtained from body's userData) position and zRotation properties.

Those are the essential steps. Just because Sprite Kit has physics built-in doesn't mean you can't use other physics engines.

Comment: Yeah, correct. You know, @Stefen, I can say that ObjectiveC-wrapped Box2D was the only reason I was thinking to possibly move from Cocos2D to Sprite kIt. (I still find C++ a bit difficult to get used to) But this one and tons of other issues prove that I'd better stick to Cocos2D, at least until iOS 9, by which time I'll be comfortable with C++ :)

Comment: Since I'm just digging deeper in the classes, SKPhysicsContact has indeed an ivar named _collisionImpulse which you can access via [self valueForKey:@"collisionImpulse"] - however that constitutes a private API use that Apple disallows in it's developer agreement.

Comment: Hmmm. Have you closed these gaps in Kobold Kit? I see you have made lots of improvements on what Sprite Kit is missing.

Comment: No, I avoid private APIs unless it's for debugging purposes. I've been thinking about adding a custom physics solution for SK but haven't had time or need.